# Can I be fired if a customer stole another customer's wallet from my counter?

Tags: work-environment

I am a cashier at cvs pharmacy . A customer I rang up left his wallet on my counter
 I did not notice it but another customer stole it.  Can I be fired over this I honestly did not notice it
I feel terrible over the whole situation.

Comment: How do you know it was stolen if you didn't notice it?

Comment: If you didn't notice then how do you know it was stolen? How do you know who the rightful owner is? Something isn't adding up in what you're telling us. If you believe that a crime has been committed than you ought to be telling your manager and the police, not posting your question on the internet.

Comment: This depends on the jursidiction.

Comment: I'm voting to re-open this as it does relate to the workplace but the OP needs to re-write the question a little. First, yes, you can be fired for any reason if you are working in an at-will state. They can fire you for any reason, whether it's a made up rule or not. You might have a case for wrongful termination or if they fire you on the grounds of some federal/state protected reasons but otherwise you can be fired any time, any where, for any reason.

Answer (score 11):

You have to be clear what your responsibilities are.

#### You are responsible for:

- Letting your manager know
- Provide appropriate statements to the police
- General sympathy to the customer

#### You are **NOT** responsible for:

- The actual theft
- The recovery of the theft
- Compensation of the theft

Your position is that you are part of the scene where the crime took place, and you can provide assistance with regards to getting in touch with the store manager, but you are not actually responsible for the theft, and you were not the designated "wallet watcher". Feeling bad is normal, but make it very clear in your own mind that "**you did not steal the wallet**" and "**you did not assist in the theft of the wallet**".

Anyone that tries to blame you for it is not being reasonable.  Being fired for it is probably illegal, but INAL and that is dependent on local laws.  (If it's actually legal, it would be due to "at will firing", not because the OP was actually responsible.)

Comment: The problem is it doesn't matter if a wallet was actually stolen or not. Depending on how the customer behaves and how the OP behaves, they might ultimately fire him. We're in the USA where most employees are at-will workers which mean they could be fired for any reason, whether for imaginary reasons or for actual reasons.

Comment: I seen situations where a waitress was fired for customers walking out on her table. It's a sad world we live in where someone else's action can get you fired but truth is it really depends on your behavior after being accused of wrongdoing. You should remain calm and factual about what happened and don't finger point or say any sort of opinion. Don't lose your cool because of someone and you'll come out on top.

Answer (score 7):

I basically agree with Kilisi's answer, but with some slight changes.

Inform you boss as soon as possible, if that has not already been done. Ask for any video to be preserved and examined. You should not touch the video yourself, because if anything goes wrong you could be suspected of destroying the video because it showed something you needed to hide.

As I understand the situation, the customer has told you he left the wallet, but you did not see it. That is all you really know, and all you should tell your boss. You have no independent knowledge of whether there really was a wallet or not.

Answer (score 6):

> Can I he fired over this

That's unlikely but unknown

However do your duty. Ascertain if a wallet was in fact left if you have video footage, and who touched it. Then inform your boss.

If there is no video footage and you never saw a wallet on the counter then just say that.

Comment: Correct. Unfortunately in the USA most employees are at-will which means you can be fired for any reason. If the OP remains factual about the missing wallet, then chances are the boss will side with him and just tell the customer. I would caution that when you're accused of wrong doing in a workplace, just remain factual and don't point fingers or say "you wish you had..." or something.